# Verbose mode startup

Tags: macos, startup, macbook-pro

I've been having sporadic issues where my Macbook Pro Retina hangs at startup.  I started up in verbose mode and it always hangs at this message.

```
AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
```

After several minutes it continues with these two message.

```
IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished():
```

What do those messages mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AppleUSBMultitouchDriver

is your touchpad, it has some problems but eventually it does it, however, I would recommend the Internet recovery (cmd-opt-r) to reinstall the driver.

The

> IO80211Controller

is your Network interface 802.11 making a note.

Comment: Do you think it's getting stuck at AppleUSBMultitouchDriver or IO80211Controller?